# wget Failed with No route to host wget

Tags: linux, apache, networking, wget, httpd.conf

I have installed apache file server(IP:192.168.100.25) on centos  vm.From another cent os vm(IP:192.168.100.26) on the same network i am trying to download files from the file server using wget

command: wget --no-proxy http://192.168.100.25/FileTOdownload

I have stopped ip tables and from fileserver i could download the file but not from another machine
In httpd configuration file i gave server name as file server ip.From other machine i could ping file server

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your default gateway & DNS server addresses on the machine where Apache is installed, then restart Apache.

Same goes for any other machine you're using browsers on, including headless browsers such as "wget".